# How to insert a footnote into word using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word

I am currently using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application** for a c# desktop application project and I need to insert footnotes in my document automatically using c#.  I have searched many different places but have not found a solution which works for me.

I am using visual studio 2010, c#, word 2007, WPF

Thanks.

EDIT:
Solutions I have tried:

-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211955%28v=office.12%29.aspx (This is visual basic)

-Solutions that include xml

I need solutions that are C# and C# only

Comment: What have you tried?  What is it about the solutions you found that doesn't work for you?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211955%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: or [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.footnotes.add.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.footnotes.add.aspx)

Comment: @Christopher Currens - I am currently trying your suggestion and seeing if this works in my solution.  Thank you

Comment: sometimes I record a macro that does what I want, and look for clues in the generated VBA code that point me to the right (dynamic) method - everything is dynamic so intellisense doesn't help right?

Comment: I am currently creating a desktop application which creates reports from our database.  I have set up the entire application however a late request was to add footnotes to the application.  Hence my question and my strict requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Document doc = app.ActiveDocument;

object selStart = 12;
object selEnd = 14;
object missing = Type.Missing;
object footnote = "This is a footnote";

Range range = doc.Range(ref selStart, ref selEnd);
doc.Footnotes.Add(range, ref missing, footnote);
```

I haven't tested it, but that would be a rough outline of how to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Only thing that I needed to change: string footnote = Test; doc.Footnotes.Add(range, ref missing, footnote); (no ref when using string)

Comment: A Range is just a starting and ending character.  I would assume word would put the footnote on the same page that you've selected text.

Comment: Yup, please see my comment above.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx). You can generate/modify word, excel and powerpoint files from pure C# code without the need of interop and office installed on the server (in case of a web app).

Comment: I've found this to be quite difficult, and I'd be interested to see some source that leverages it in a meaningful way - I just tend to get lost in the depths of the schema hierarchy.

Comment: I don't know how this helps me put a single footnote in an application that I have been already created without starting over.  Can this be added as a DLL? Or some sort of other class?

Comment: @Gabriel It is very tricky. I think that XML schema more or less morphed over from RTF, which has been growing organically since it was first conceived :P There's usually more than one completely different way to represent everything, so it gets tricky if you're trying to _read_ it.

Comment: @Gabriel If you use the Xml class explorer you will be able to find a little more easily where to "touch". I started from this post http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/06/02/4730.aspx

Comment: @bvandrunen it's a dll. So you can open your doc, editing it and save to file or stream